# What's the best way to check if C code has deprecated POSIX calls?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, unix

I've been working on some older C code. I found out that there are quite some POSIX calls that are now outdated and marked **deprecated** in the manual pages.

What's the best way to check if there are still deprecated POSIX calls in your code? I'm thinking of either:

- special **gcc warning** options.
- some kind of **lint** tool detecting these calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Lint](http://www.gimpel.com/Discussion.cfm#2) can find deprecated things (-deprecated flag).

[Coverity](http://www.coverity.com/) finds this kind of issue routinely with c and c++ codebases.

Additionally, and perhaps more importantly, static analysis tools find a very much wider range of issues and bugs.

You can never have too much static code analysis.  There is benefit from using several tools.

Answer (score 4):

My first attempt would be a simple tool using `grep` (even though it may throw up false positives).

```
>> cd src_dir

>> cat deprecated_calls
printf
strcpy

>> for i in $(cat deprecated_calls) ; do
+>     grep -R $i .
+> done
binmath.c:printf ("   0 sum:[%s]\n",sum);
binmath.c:printf (" 100 sum:[%s]\n",sum);
binmath.c:printf (" 200 sum:[%s]\n",sum);
binmath.c:printf (" 300 sum:[%s]\n",sum);
qq.c:printf("%d %d %d\n",i,j,k);
xx.c:        fprintf (stderr, "Cannot open 'words.txt', error = %d\n", errno);
binmath.c:strcpy (buff, "0");
oldstuff/qq.c:printf("%d %d %d\n",i,j,k);
```

I doubt you need a full-blown parser-type tool for this.

Comment: Might we recommend ack here? If the OP has access to Perl, ack will save lives.

Comment: Nice idea if we assume there is nothing already that do this. But how do we get a text file of all POSIX deprecated calls?

Comment: @Chris Lutz : I'm not familiar with ack, where to get it or what it does.

Comment: But this may be swatting a fly with a jackhammer :-)